# 3 Node Cluster for Elastic, Kafka and Cassandra - On 3 Machines

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, apache-kafka

We are creating a 3 node elastic cluster, but want to use each of our 3 elastic nodes for other things, like Kafka and Cassandra.  We need high availability, so we want to have 3 nodes for everything, but we don't want to have 9 machines, we just want to put them on one bigger computer. Is this a typical scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I would say no.

One sandbox machine running a PoC with all the components local, sure, why not. But Production with HA requirements, you are just asking for trouble putting everything in one place. They're going to compete for resource, one blowing the box up kills the others, touching the machine to change one risks the others, etc, etc.

IMO keep your architecture clean and deploy on separate nodes for each component.

Comment: Would containerization help in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, potentially.